# By module of function to determine the function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $D = \{ z \in \mathbb { C } \mid | z | < 1 \} , \overline { D }$ and
>   $\partial D$ denote the closure and the boundary of $D ,$
>    respectively. Let $f$ and $g$ be functions holomolphic on $D$ and
>    continuous on $\overline { D } ,$ which satisfy the following three
>   conditions: $$\begin{array} { c l } { | f ( z ) | \leq | g ( z ) | } &
>  { ( z \in D ) } \\ { | f ( z ) | = | g ( z ) | } & { ( z \in \partial
>  D ) } \\ { f ( z ) \neq 0 } & { ( z \in \overline { D } \backslash \{
>  0 \} ) } \end{array}$$ Show there exist $\alpha \in \mathbb { C }$
>   with $| \alpha | = 1$ and $m \in \mathbb { N } \cup \{ 0 \}$ such that
>   $f ( z ) =$ $\alpha z ^ { m } g ( z ) .$

Is there Schwarz Lemma usable? What tools should I use to solve the problem?

Comment: I tried to Taylor expand two functions at point x to find what I can get but I do it in vain. So what is the correct way to solve the problem?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to do it, but an equivalent problem is (set $h=f/g$) to show that any continuous function $h: \overline{D}\rightarrow \overline{D}$ which is holomorphic in $D$, $h(z)\neq 0$ for $z\neq 0$ and $\vert h(z)\vert =1$ for $\vert z\vert =1$ is of the form $h(z)= \alpha \cdot z^m$ for $\vert \alpha\vert =1$.

Comment: This is a well known result about Blaschke functions, namely that holomorphic functions in the disc, continuous on the boundary and of absolute value 1 on the boundary are finite Blaschke products. In this case just factor out the zero at origin for h with a power of z, noting that it doesn't change what happens on the boundary, and using now the new h non zero everywhere, its reciprocal satisfies same, apply maximum modulus to conclude...

Comment: Thanks for your generous comment! Do you interested in write down the solution of this problem in answer chart?  I desire to see the solution in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h: \overline{D}\rightarrow \overline{D}$, holomorphic in $D$, continuos in $\overline{D}$, $h(0)=0$, $h(z)\neq 0$ if $z\neq 0$, $\vert h(z)\vert =1$ on the boundary $\vert z\vert =1$. Let integer $m \geq 1$ the order of $h$ at zero (because $h$ holomorphic this makes sense) and let $q(z)=\frac{h(z)}{z^m}$. Since $\vert z^m\vert =1$ on the boundary, $q$ satifies the same properties as $h$ except that it is non-zero everywhere in the disc. But then $\frac{1}{q}$ is also holomorphic in the disc, continuos on the boundary and of absolute value 1 there. Apply the maximum modulus to q first, to get $\vert q(z)\vert \leq 1$ in the disc and then to $\frac{1}{q}$, to get $\vert\frac{1}{q(z)}\vert  \leq 1$ in the disc, conclude that $\vert q(z)\vert = 1$ in the disc, so $q$ constant $\alpha$ of modulus 1, so $h(z)= \alpha z^m$